# How to use NDEigenvalue to accurately estimate functional determinants?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, numerical-value

**Goal**: Ultimately, I would like to find a *trustworthy* approximation for the ratio of the functional determinant of two differential operators using the formula
$$ \frac{\text{Det}[\hat{D}_0]}{\text{Det}[\hat{D}]} =\frac{\prod^\infty_i \lambda_{0,i}}{\prod^\infty_j \lambda_j}  \approx \frac{\prod^N_i \lambda_{0,i}}{\prod^N_j \lambda_j} $$
where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of the respective operators and $N$ is the number of eigenvalues used in the approximation.

**Step 1**: *defining the operators*.

To define these two operators I first must solve the following coupled ODE boundary value problem in $\phi(t)$ and $p_\phi(t)$. The system depends on the parameter $\tau > 0$.

```
bvp = {D[p\[Phi][t], 
t] == (-(1/\[Tau]))*
 p\[Phi][t]^2*(Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]/2) + (1/\[Tau])*p\[Phi][t]*
 Cos[2*\[Phi][t]] + (1/\[Tau])*(Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]/2), 
D[\[Phi][t], t] == 
 2*Pi - ((1/\[Tau])*Sin[2*\[Phi][t]])/2 + (1/\[Tau])*p\[Phi][t]*
 Sin[\[Phi][t]]^2, \[Phi][0] == 
 2*ArcTan[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*Pi^2*\[Tau]^2])/(2*Pi*\[Tau])], \[Phi][
1] == 2*ArcTan[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*Pi^2*\[Tau]^2])/(2*Pi*\[Tau])] + 
2*Pi}
```

Which is readily solved with

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[bvp, {\[Phi][t], p\[Phi][t]}, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Tau]}]
```

Using these solutions I can define the two differential operators (which depend on a choice of parameter $\tau$ and the numerical solution of $\phi(t)$) with Dirichlet boundary conditions

$\hat{D}_0$

```
{-D[\[Tau]*Csc[sol[\[Tau]][[1]]]^2*D[\[Psi][t], t], t], \[Psi][0] == 
 0, \[Psi][1] == 0}
```

and $\hat{D}$

```
{-D[\[Tau]*Csc[sol[\[Tau]][[1]]]^2*D[\[Psi][t], t], t] + (2*\[Tau]*Cot[sol[\[Tau]] 
[[1]]]*Csc[sol[\[Tau]][[1]]]^2*D[sol[\[Tau]][[1]], {t, 2}] - 
\[Tau]*Csc[sol[\[Tau]][[1]]]^4*(Cos[2*sol[\[Tau]][[1]]] + 2)*D[sol[\[Tau]][[1]], t]^2 + 
2*Pi*Csc[sol[\[Tau]][[1]]]^4*(2*Pi*\[Tau]*(Cos[2*sol[\[Tau]][[1]]] + 2) - Sin[2*sol[\[Tau]] 
[[1]]]))*\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == 0, 
\[Psi][1] == 0}
```

**Step 2**: *Numerically calculating the eigenvalues*.

First selecting a particular value of the parameter $\tau$ to be $0.1$, I use the inbuilt function NDEigenvalue to numerically calculate N=39 Eigenvalues for $\hat{D}_0$ and multiply them together

```
Times @@ NDEigenvalues[{-D[0.1*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^2*D[\[Psi][t], t], t], \[Psi][0] == 0, 
\[Psi][1] == 0}, \[Psi][t], {t, 0, 1}, 39]
```

Similarly for $\hat{D}$

```
Times @@ NDEigenvalues[{-D[0.1*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^2*D[\[Psi][t], t], t] + 
 (2*0.1*Cot[sol[0.1][[1]]]*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^2*D[sol[0.1][[1]], {t, 2}] - 
   0.1*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^4*(Cos[2*sol[0.1][[1]]] + 2)*D[sol[0.1][[1]], t]^2 + 
   2*Pi*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^4*(2*Pi*0.1*(Cos[2*sol[0.1][[1]]] + 2) - Sin[2*sol[0.1][[1]]]))*\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == 0, 
\[Psi][1] == 0}, \[Psi][t], {t, 0, 1}, 39]
```

Then I simply take the ratio. I do this also for additional choices of the parameter $\tau$.

**The issue**: The accuracy of this approximation is not good enough for small values of the parameter $\tau$.

From the underlying physics, I strongly expect that

- The ratio will be a **monotonically increasing function of $\tau$**

Unfortunately, after *calculating a few of these ratios* in the parameter range $ 0<\tau<1 $, I find that the ratios do not appear to be monotonically increasing. Additionally, **the order of magnitude seems to change** significantly as I change $N$, the number of eigenvalues used in the approximation. These two things make me conclude the numerical solutions I have so far are untrustworthy.

If I try to increase the number of Eigenvalues used in the approximation beyond 39 I get an error message saying "A maximum number of 39 eigenvalues and functions can be computed for this discretized system."

[image]

**Solution Attempt**:

My main guess at how to solve this issue is to find a way to increase the number of eigenvalues that NDEigenvalue returns.

1. I have tried to increase the accuracy of the parametric solutions for $\phi(t)$, but this did not seem to help very much
2. I have also tried to change methods used in NDEigenvalues (see the code below)

   ```
   NDEigenvalues[{-D[0.1*Csc[sol[0.1][[1]]]^2*D[\[Psi][t], t],t], \[Psi][0] == 0, 
   \[Psi][1] == 0}, \[Psi][t], {t, 0, 1}, 70, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> 
   {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}}]
   ```

This will return about 60 eigenvalues before returning another error message (see image below) but has the same issue as the original method and will also sometimes find eigenvalues that when compared with the set of the first 39 eigenvalues found by the default method are sometimes an order of magnitude different!

[image]

So far all of this code runs fairly quickly, so I feel that there should be a way to get Mathematica to think for longer and find more eigenvalues but so far I have not found how to do this in a satisfactory way. I do not know if there are other ways I should be trying to solve my problem and would very much appreciate any advice I can get on how to make progress.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: There is a typo in the first line of you code with not open ( ) `bvp = {D[p\[Phi][t], 
      t] == (-(1/\[Tau]))*p\[Phi][t]^2*(Sin[2*\[Phi][t]]/2) + 
      1/\[Tau])*...`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will edit my question to fix this and other errors that may have crept in while formatting my question.

Comment: The typo issue should be resolved now!

Comment: What about using perturbation theory and a Jacobi formula i.e. det(A + hB) for small h is equal to det (A) + h Tr(adj(A)B) ?

Comment: Hi @yarchik, I can see how I could start to apply your method for evaluating the determinant for my second differential operator where your h is my \tau. But I don't see how this could help for the operator D_0?

Comment: What is the boundary condition on pphi? Also, does this help: `sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  bvp, {\[Phi][t], p\[Phi][t]}, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Tau]}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]`

Comment: Hi @user21, there are not meant to be any boundary conditions imposed on pphi! Improving the accuracy of the parametric solutions does not make any more eigenvalues accessible, and the other issues mentioned still persist

Comment: @incoherent_state Do you know a theorem about convergence of your system?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm afraid not. These operators fail to be a regular Strum-Liouville problem because the coefficients are not always continuous on the interval of interest.  And given that there is not a closed-form expression for the two operators also makes it more difficult for me to know where to start on the theory side of things. I know the ratio should always be positive because it is a contributing factor in an probability where the other factors are know and positive.

Comment: Correction: It is a contributing factor to a probability density

Comment: See `NDEigensystem#2089437715` in the documentation about, getting more eigenvalues. You will need to refine the mesh. Try to use the same mesh for `ParametricNDSolve` and `NDEigensystem` and see if that helps.

Comment: @incoherent_state The numerical problem is that you have to use second order derivative in $\hat{D}$ while `sol` is a solution of the first order system `bvp`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I should be able to convert the ODE system that is first order in \phi and p\phi into a system that is second order in \phi only, do you think this would help?

Comment: @user21 changing the methods used by `ParametricNDSolve` with `Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001}}` I find that PDEsolve cannot find a solution! Would you continue just refining the mesh, or am I implementing your solution with the wrong code?

Comment: @user21 also would the correct method in `NDEigensystem` be the same as the approach mentioned in my question: `Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> 
{"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have converted the ODE system into the equivalent first-order problem, but I am still unable to calculate additional eigenvalues? I have also tested using a closed-form solution to define the differential operators (just a straight line between the boundary values) but I am still limited to only 39 Eigenvalues!